# Get value of a jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $x = $("input[name='" + linkedmodule + "']");
//var x=document.getElementsByName(linkedmodule);

console.log($x);
if ($x !== "" || $x !== "undefined" || $x !== null) {
    linkedid = $x.val();
    linked_module = $x.attr("relatedModule");
    console.log(linkedid);
} else {

}
```

I am getting an undefined in the linkedid Please could someone help me

Comment: Need your markup to be able to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Looks like `$x` is not returning any results. None of those tests in the `if` statement are going to work anyway, replace it with `if($x.length) { ... }`. jQuery will never return `""`, `"undefined"` or `null` from a selector.

Comment: As @RGraham said, the problem is that $x may be returning nothing. I did a fiddle with your javascript (and some sample html) and it's ok: http://jsfiddle.net/ogopmb5d/ take a look at your html markup.

Comment: make sure the selector you are using is valid .. please provide the html for more assistance

Comment: It is returning a value

Comment: @vini Update your question with the markup as has been asked for, please. We can't help otherwise.

Comment: @RGraham *"None of those tests in the if statement are going to work"* : those tests will work, exactly the way it should. There is no problem with js :). It's just that OP might have thought it'd work differently.

Comment: @TJ Semantics. The explanation is more important than the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code object ($x) empty check is not proper,

Below is the modified code

```
var $x = $("input[name='" + linkedmodule + "']");
//var x=document.getElementsByName(linkedmodule);

console.log($x);
if (!($x === undefined || $x == null || $x.length <= 0)) {
    linkedid = $x.val();
    linked_module = $x.attr("relatedModule");
  console.log("Value of the element : "+ linkedid);
} else {

}
```